# Javascript framework calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Does any know of a good calendar (not datepicker, but a BIG browsable calendar) plugin for one of the major javascript frameworks.  I'd prefer jQuery.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

just published a new open source project (jQuery plugin). sounds exactly like what you want:

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Hope it works well for you!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer [Eyecon Calendar.](http://eyecon.ro/datepicker/) Maybe the best.

Comment: Really good and with a nice and simple style.

Answer (score 4):

i think you will like the following:

[Date Range Picker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker/)

vote it if you like it

Comment: One of the best I've seen in some few time.

Answer (score 4):

Useful Calendar & Date Picker Scripts For Web Developers:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-calendar-date-picker-scripts-for-web-developers/

Comment: Link doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

This is quite good resource for jQuery Calendar implemenation

Answer (score 4):

why not try this jquery event calendar http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/. This is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to send the guys at [jCalendar](http://tedserbinski.com/jcalendar/index.html#about) a note. They were working on a Google Calendar-like jQuery plugin.  Project seems to have moved on, but they may be able to point you in the right direction.

From their site:

> Coming soon will be v1.0, which will allow for not only visually selecting dates but also for displaying them in both mini and full page calendar views, similar to that of Google Calendar.

Comment: Outdated. jCalendar has been discontinued and the author admitted being superceded by jQuery UI. I suppose best way of keeping this question clean over time is deleting this answer, but @patrickyoung has not visited SO for more than a year, so I downvoted instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one I put together. It looks and works like Google Calendar.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used http://www.stefanoverna.com/log/create-astonishing-ical-like-calendars-with-jquery

Comment: Link not available anymore.