# jquerymobile - weekly calendar

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript (jquery) calendar plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78703/javascript-jquery-calendar-plugin)

I am going to develop the weekly calendar plungin in jquery. Please give some guidance where and how will I start the concept. 1)  I want to display starting days/dates of the week for the current month / Particural month  2) And also make the navigation between the months by previous and next buttons.

I am started to working but initially I want some guidance. Please share your views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below link to the jquery Weekly calender plugin 
this one is inspired by google calender,easy to use and has many functionalities added to it

https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar