# updating the events in jquery fullcalendar(arshaw's)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fullcalendar

I am learning ROR by doing a project mananagement system. If a project manager assigns tasks to a team member by selecting the due date from the datepicker, and once it is saved it should automatically update in arshaw fullcalendar. I am able to save the tasks assigned. How do I update it in jquery calendar.?? Any inputs on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Refer this Link [fullcalendar][1] It will give some idea about Jquery Calendar


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78703/javascript-framework-calendar-plugin

Comment: I have integrated the arshaw calendar into my ROR application. But I am not getting an idea of how to update the tasks in it.