# Calendar View With DataTables (Or Alternative Plug-in)?

Tags: jquery, plugins, calendar, datatables

I currently have a system that lists events and their dates using DataTables ([datatables.net](http://datatables.net))

It works well this way; you can filter it down by date, search by event name, sort by date, and it's paginated. However, ideally, I'd like to be able to display the same data with the same filtering functionality but in a calendar view paged by month.

I may not be thinking hard enough, but I can't seem to think of a way of adapting DataTables to display its data in a calendar format. Do you have any suggestions for how best to tackle this?

Or do I need to look at an alternative solution? If so, can you recommend any other plug-ins  that provide similar functionality to DataTables (searching/filtering/pagination) but with a calendar view?

Comment: Basically, you are looking for a JavaScript option, that'll allow you to display a calendar with integrated events. i.e. days-of-the-month view with events in their corresponding day-box. Something like Google.Calendar perhaps?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78703/javascript-framework-calendar-plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, jQuery DataTables cannot be presented in calendar form - in the end, it's a tables plug-in, not a calendar plugin...(although I do get that a calendar can be viewed as a special case of a table). Here are some links:

- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/04/jquery-calendar-date-pickers.html
- [Javascript framework calendar plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78703/javascript-framework-calendar-plugin)
- http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
- http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/

Comment: I used table headings instead of a calendar view in the end, as it was easier and cleaner and could still be done using DataTables. this may come in handy in the future, though, thanks.